# Removing the Stage in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

How can the KineticJS `Stage` be removed?

**Problem:** `stage.removeChildren()` successfully removes its children like `layers`. However `stage.remove()` does not remove the stage, as shown in the jsfiddle below where `console.log(stage)` after removing it still shows that the stage has not been removed!!!

*The div `.kineticjs-content` that was created along with a `Kinetic.Stage` also remained after the `.remove()` was executed.*

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jfaUg/

Comment: The latest Kinetic JS allows stage removal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stage cannot be removed as there is no remove function applicable as per the current state of KineticJS.

```
.remove()
```

function that you are trying to use is applicable for children of "Container" class ([documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Container.php#remove)) and not the Container Object itself (Stage extends Container)
i.e. to say
`layer.remove()` works but `stage.remove()` won't

Comment: Hope it'll be added soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always add:

```
stage=null;
document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = '';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfaUg/1/